# NSString - how to convert LONDON into London

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

How can I convert a string @"NEW YORK" into @"New York", or "LONDON" into "London"?

Thanks,

RL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *allCapsString = @"LONDON";
NSString *city = [allCapsString capitalizedString];
NSLog(@"%@", city); // @"London"
```